# Auto Enable radio button

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that I made for my radio buttons. My page has three lines, each with three different radio buttons. What I'd like to come up with is a way to control radiobuttons in line 2 and 3 when the user clicks a radio button in line 1, like:

- when I select radio btn #1 it will automatically disable radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3. Now if im going to change the selection in Line 1 like selecting this time radio btn #2, it should enable the radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3. What is the right way to do it?

```js
    $('.Session').click(function(){
     if(this.value == 'One1' && this.checked){
       console.log($('input[value=One2], input[value=One3'));
       $('input[value=One2], input[value=One3]').prop('disabled', true);
     }
     else if(this.value == 'One2' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=One1], input[value=One3]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if(this.value == 'One3' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=One1], input[value=One2]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }

    else if(this.value == 'Bk1' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Bk2], input[value=Bk3]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }
    else if(this.value == 'Bk2' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Bk1], input[value=Bk3]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }
    else if(this.value == 'Bk3' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Bk1], input[value=Bk2]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }

    else if(this.value == 'Test1' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Test2], input[value=Test3]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }
    else if(this.value == 'Test2' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Test1], input[value=Test3]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }
    else if(this.value == 'Test3' && this.checked){
      $('input[value=Test1], input[value=Test2]').prop('disabled', true);   
    }
    else{
      $('.Session').not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Line 1 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk1">1
    <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="One1">2
    <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test1">3
  </div>
<label> Line 2 </label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk2">1
    <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="One2">2
    <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test2">3
  </div>
<label> Line 3 </label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk3">1
    <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="One3">2
    <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test3">3
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `index` of selected radio and `disable` all the other `radio`'s with the same index, check example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.Session').click(function(){
  var checkbox_index = $(this).index();

  $('.input-group').each(function(){
    $('input:eq('+checkbox_index+')', this).prop('disabled',true);
  })

  $(this).prop('disabled',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Line 1 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk1">1
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="One1">2
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test1">3
</div>
<label> Line 2 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk2">1
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="One2">2
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test2">3
</div>
<label> Line 3 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk3">1
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="One3">2
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="Test3">3
</div>
```

Comment: when i select radio btn #1 it will automatically disable radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3. Now if im going to change the selection in Line 1 like selecting this time radio btn #2, it should enable the radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3.

Comment: Is that not what happen here? what's the problem in this solution?

Comment: Sir I'd tried the code you'd posted earlier but it should be this way like when i select radio btn #1 it will automatically disable radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3. When i select radio btn 2 or 3 in Line 2,the radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3 should remain disabled. But in your code the radio btn #1 in Line 2 and 3 will be enabled again.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't really understand the way you want from your description (check my updated answer the disabled remain disabled) is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Working with html's [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) is the quickest way to do that. Simply add a data attribute with a unique name and a value for each kind of button (like "one", "two", "three") and use it to select the buttons (you could also use data attributes and classes, but if you don't need to run anything else on that buttons the only pro of that is a slightly improved readability).

```js
$('.Session').click(function(){
     if(this.checked){
         var clicked = $(this);
         var position = clicked.data('radio-position');
         $('.input-group input').prop('disabled',false);
         $('.input-group').find('[data-radio-position=' + position + ']').each(function(radio){
             if(radio != clicked){
                 $(radio).prop('disabled', true);
                 $(radio).prop('checked', false);
             }
          });
      }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Line 1 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="one" value="Bk1">1
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="two" value="One1">2
  <input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="three" value="Test1">3
</div>
<label> Line 2 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="one" value="Bk2">1
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="two" value="One2">2
  <input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="three" value="Test2">3
</div>
<label> Line 3 </label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="one" value="Bk3">1
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="two" value="One3">2
  <input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" data-radio-position="three" value="Test3">3
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, the selected button in each line should be unique. So if i select rBtn #1 in Line 1 and if i select  rBtn #1 in Line 2,the rBtn #1 in Line 1 is now should be  unselected and at the same time disabled so as for rBtn #1 in line 3 be disabled.

Comment: I'll update my answer but I don't get how the user could select a disabled button, is there any other script that work on the same form?